# Installation issue with yo generator

Tags: node.js, osx-yosemite, yeoman-generator-angular

Trying to install the yo angular module like this:

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

I am getting this error:

```
! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.11.1 wants generator-karma@>=0.9.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular-js@1.0.1 wants generator-karma@~0.6.0
```

What is the way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install all the dependancies for yo angular as well.  Trying running:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```